# Ionic advanced-http: header values must be strings

Tags: ionic-framework

Ionic Showing error on device console Error: advanced-http: invalid params object, needs to be an object with strings
Error: advanced-http: invalid params object, needs to be an object with strings.

```
  private http: HTTP
   verify(){

      this.http.get('http://outreach.pk/api/sendsms.php/sendsms/url?id=rchiginsurance&pass=igi123456&mask=IGInsurance&lang=English&type=xml',
         {
  params: {
  to: this.mobile.value,
  msg: this.number1
  }
  },
   {});

  }
```

Comment: are you sure that your sending all the params??

Comment: Yes sending all params . Same problem comes in other url aswell.

Comment: then u need to check your back end first and api code in backend file

Comment: Its working fine ftom back  . i do by same way from "@angular/http" but its showing error of cors block thats why im using HTTP Native now showing this error .

Comment: in that case use some cros enablers or do it in server

Comment: cros extension work only on browser i need to run it on device . Thats why using http native

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193631/discussion-between-sa-e-chowdary-and-umaiz-khan).

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the headers for the request by using `set` as shown:

```
this.http.setHeader('*', String("Content-Type"), String("application/json"));
this.http.setHeader('*', String("Accept"), String("application/json"));
```

and you need to set the serializer

```
this.http.setDataSerializer('json');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your header is empty, just put "null" for headers object and set serializer. For example:

```
this.http.setDataSerializer("json");
this.http.post(url, body, null).then(res => {....});
```

or

```
this.http.setDataSerializer("json");
this.http.post(url, body, {headers: {'Content-Type: application/json'}}).then(res => {....});
```

im writing this on ionic capacitor 2.4 and ionic-native/http 5.29